# Show that the image of $\lambda$ has zero content in $\mathbb R^n$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, functions

Let $\lambda:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$  be a class curve $C^1$ Part by part. Then, the imagem of $\lambda$ has  null content in $\mathbb R^n$.
My attempt, let $\epsilon > 0$, let's consider a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, such that for any subrectangle $R$ of P,  $\lambda$ is $C^1$ in $R$. Where $\int_R \lambda$  exists,
since $\partial R$ has zero content in $\mathbb R^n$, and $\lambda$ is  $C^1$ in $R$ and limited.
so I can think in $$S(\lambda,P)-s(\lambda,P) < \epsilon $$
where  this forms the finite coverage of  imagem of $\lambda$.
Is this correct?